# Subset as circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

is there any easy way to draw a subsets as circles, as in the picture below?
[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried. This site is not a do-it-for-me service.

Comment: The answer depends on what you consider as "easy". Maybe see this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/691593/47927

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you, this is what I was looking for!